# Array is nil after appending to it

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 Types, first is `Car` with property `feature` and it of the second type `Feature`.

I have a property `cars: [Car]`, when I append new car to it, it returns `nil`.

I have created a sample in the snippet below:

```
class Car {
    let make: String
    var features: Feature?
    let id: String

    init(make: String, features: Feature?, id: String) {
        self.make = make
        self.features = features
        self.id = id
    }
}

class Feature {
    let convertible: String

    init(convertible: String) {
        self.convertible = convertible
    }

}

var cars: [Car]?
var feature: Feature?

let featureElement = Feature(convertible: "yes")
feature = featureElement

let car = Car(make: "SomeMaked", features: feature, id: "ID")

cars?.append(car)

print(cars)
```

**My question is**: Shouldn't the array increase its count after appening to it? What am I missing?

*Please note that this code is just sample, so ignore typos and coding convention.*

Comment: Why are the `features` parameter and `features` property named `features` instead of `feature`? Only use plural when you can pass or store more than one value.

Comment: @rmaddy **Please note that this code is just sample, so ignore typos and coding convention.**

Comment: If you want help with code, you need to post actual code causing your issue. Otherwise you waste people's time pointing out issues that may or may not actually exist.

Comment: Really? Didn't know breaking code convention produces errors in code.

Comment: No but typos and other "fake" code wastes people's time. It's always best to post real, actual, copy and pasted code clearly demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Well I do agree it’s best, but it only best and nothing more. It does NOT waste people’s time unless they kept discussing it should follow coding conventions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't initialized your array.

Replace your `var cars: [Car]?` with `var cars: [Car]? = []`

Comment: Why make it optional? Just do: `var cards = [Car]()`

Comment: @rmaddy I wanted to suggest that, but if the OP had created it not optional, OP wouldn't have figured out that this caveat. Now hopefully, next time they come across some issue like this, they'll be able to debug it. :)

Comment: @rmaddy The OP has an optional. How can you know that `cars` cannot be `nil` on code execution?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Given the posted code there is no obvious reason to make the array an optional.

Comment: @rmaddy That's true. But SO requires to post minimal code and most users post at least reduced code. So the assumption is akin of courageous.